# Injected ViewModels are not visible in a WPF content control unless re-initialised

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, contentcontrol, stylet

I have a content control as follows:

```
<ContentControl 
    x:Name="GraphArea"
    s:View.Model="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

This binds to the following property in my ViewModel:

```
private Screen selectedViewModel;

public Screen SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set{SetAndNotify(ref this.selectedViewModel, value);}
    }
```

I then have a second ViewModel called GisViewModel which is injected as follows using Stylet.

```
[Inject]
public GisViewModel GisViewModel { get; set; }
```

I then insert my GisViewModel into my SelectedViewModel property as follows:

```
public void LoadMap()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = GisViewModel;
    }
```

But doing this displays nothing in the ContentControl.

If however I do the following, the content control loads great, but I don't want to create a new GISViewModel just to view it.

```
public void LoadMap()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new GisViewModel();
    }
```

Why is the newly initiallised GisViewModel visible in my content control, but not the injected version?

Comment: Make sure that GisViewModel is not null.

Comment: Of course, feel daft now. It was because I hadn't registered the overarching ViewModel in the IOC so the GISViewModel couldn't be injected. All sorted now. Thanks